# Line graph not working with concat function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using concat function in my query to use '$' sign with fee. The problem I am facing is, line graph is rendering without concat function but not working with concat.
I am using [blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer) gem.

Here is my query.

**With concat:**

```
select date_trunc('month', (bookings.created_at)::timestamp)::date as dt, 
concat('$', avg(bookings.total_fee_usd)) as total_rent 
from bookings where 
bookings.state in ('paid_in_full') 
group by dt order by dt desc
```

[image]

**Without concat**

```
select date_trunc('month', (bookings.created_at)::timestamp)::date as dt,
avg(bookings.total_fee_usd) as total_rent
from bookings
where bookings.state in ('paid_in_full')
group by dt order by dt desc
```

[image]

My requirement is to have both the line graph and a dollar "$" sign.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am also looking for the answer to this.

Comment: I think that Blazer expects only numbers to be able to create a graphic chart, it can't "measure" strings, did you try to concat each label with some JS after the chart generated?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the third-party plugin used by Blazer gem. Blazer gem has a dependency on `chartkick.js` and `chartkick.js` does not draw a line chart when if there is a special symbol included in the data set. So, for now, this can not be achieved using Blazer gem until they may update their gem and provide some way of achieving this. 
However, If you are using standalone `chartkick.js` library in your project you may pass [prefix](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js?files=1) as a parameter/argument like this: `new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-1", data, {prefix: "$"})` in order to achieve this.